# Best approach for maintaining sessions for logged in user . Which approach is the most efficient

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, jwt, express-session

While implementing authentication, what is the best approach to maintain session. So, I wanna know the best approach between the below:

1. Session-based Authentication: Server creates a session after user logged in and store the session in the DB with TTL (Example: 10 minutes) for that user. Authenticated user making successive requests will send cookie in header from client-side then server validates and updates TTL value for that cookie in DB and on the client-side(Keep-alive session).
2. JWT-based Authentication: Logged in user send's JWT Token in response. Client stores the token in localStorage and sends the token in header for making requests. JWT stored in DB with TTL value ( 10 Minutes) for that user. Authenticated user making successive requests will send token (taken from localstorage) in header from client-side then server validates and updates TTL value for that token in DB (Keep-alive session).

So, in this approach I don't have to use redis, blacklisting tokens, refresh token etc.

Also, if there is any better solution for this problem-statement kindly, provide your inputs.

Note: The backend is horizontally scaled. The techstack used in backend are  Node.js and MongoDB.

Any help, will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: #2 - you don't store the JWT, you just verify that it's still valid and extract data.  Otherwise you're just using JWT tokens as a session cookie.  For #2 without a blacklist you have no way to prevent someone from using a nonexpired token, even if they've said they want to log out or it's been compromised.

Comment: the reason to store jwt in DB is ...let's say backend is running in multiple instances (nginx load balance) JWT is created in Node-A (1st instance ) next time request comes to Node- B ( 2nd instance) Node-B cannot verify JWT right ?  Another reason, to store token in DB is for keep alive session. 

I use short expiry time and update expiry time (increase) on every  successive request in DB. 

i also sign the jwt token with browser information, atleast this way we can reduce some malicious attackers.

So, you prefer with 2nd approach ?

Comment: If the JWT secret is the same across all your Node server instances, then yes, all servers will be able to verify the JWT. Here is a longer read on JWTs: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: node A and B can validate any JWT as long as they have access to the signing key.  As you have it currently set up, I don't see how you'd invalidate a session server-side (if the user explicitly wanted to log out etc.) You just keep renewing the token or extending the session.

Comment: Hey Joe, 

Since, I am using TTL  document level, my JWT token in DB will be my index . As i get JWT Token from client on every request i find the document by JWT token . If there is no document that is returned then throw "session is expired, login again" .